# Docker consuming entire VG on Openshift v3

Tags: openshift-origin

Docker is consuming the entire `docker_vg` on a cluster node.

```
Mar 01 00:14:24 ip-172-31-3-213.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal lvm[918]: Rounding pool metadata size to boundary between physical extents: 8.00 MiB
Mar 01 00:14:24 ip-172-31-3-213.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal lvm[918]: Insufficient free space: 1630 extents needed, but only 27 available
Mar 01 00:14:24 ip-172-31-3-213.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal lvm[918]: Failed to extend thin docker_vg-docker--pool.
```

I thought there was something that was meant to release old Docker resources periodically? Or is this something I need to be managing?

Comment: I've read https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/garbage_collection.html -- there's no settings specified in my node-config.yaml

Comment: In general the node will periodically garbage collect images and old containers.  Are you using loopback or direct lvm for your docker vg?

Comment: Direct LVM as set up by the openshift-ansible playbook.